# Partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=\int_y^x\cos(e^t)dt$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How would I compute the partial derivatives of the function: $$f(x,y)=\int_y^x\cos(e^t)\:dt$$
The only thing I'm having trouble with is the integral, checking on online calculators is confusing me for some reason...

Comment: Try [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Use the rule of derivative under integral sign.

Then , $f_x=\cos (e^x)$ and $f_y=-\sin(e^y)$.

Comment: It is FTC here. Derivation under integral is another story.